# Mi promesa se esta ejecutando mas de una vez (javascript vanilla)

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas

Por alguna razon mi fetch() se esta ejecutando mas de una vez y no deberia de pasar eso. Tengo un await a ese fetch en una función, y cuando llamo a esta función y accedo a sus datos con .then() por alguna razón ejecuta nuevamente la promesa de fetch() y no deberia hacerlo porque solo tiene un await.

Esta es mi promesa, la cual agrega contenido HTML al dom de forma dinamica (se tiene que ejecutar solo una vez)

```javascript
export const getFeatures = () => {
  let feats = document.querySelector('.dynamic-feats');
  const features = './src/features/features.html';
  let exist = document.querySelector('.features');
  console.log('pasa por getFeatures al principio')
  
  return fetch(features)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      } 
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(html => {
      if(!exist) {
        feats.innerHTML = html;
      } else{
        console.error('Features already exist');
      }
     
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Y este es el codigo donde le estoy haciendo el await, es una funcion que inicializa objetos y cosas del dom luego de que se complete la promesa getFeatures()

```javascript
const waitForFeatures = async () => {
  if(!feats) { //verifico si feats no existe, si no existe es porque el html dinamico no se agergó
    await getFeatures(); 
  }
  
  const vars = {
    ... resto de mi codigo
```

Hasta acá todo bien, ahora viene el problema. Cuando accedo a la función anterior usando `.then()` para acceder a los datos del objeto vars, por alguna razon la promesa mostrada al principio se vuelve a disparar, y en consola recibo varias veces el mensaje "Features already exist", osea que paso por el else y nunca deberia de haber llegado a ese punto**

```
const showTechIcons = (e)=> {
 waitForFeatures().then((data)=> { ... accedo a data para hacer cosas...
```

Agrego showTechIcons a 3 botones, luego de que waitForFeatures() se resuelve y crea los datos que voy a usar.

```
const initializeButtons = async () => {
  await waitForFeatures(); 

   document.getElementById('btn-uses').addEventListener('click', showTechIcons);
   document.getElementById('btn-practice').addEventListener('click', showTechIcons);
   document.getElementById('btn-pro').addEventListener('click', showTechIcons);
   console.log('event listener agregado.')

};
```

Entonces cada vez que hago click en uno de estos botones, la promesa entra en el else. Por que pasa esto? alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Porfavor, añade un [mre] a la pregunta. Para empezar, tu código actual ni siquiera es válido (falta algo al principio). Segundo... pretendes que sepamos qué está pasando exactamente sin poder ejecutarlo?? Ni siquiera vemos el html asociado! Haz un [mre] que podamos *"toquetear"* y ejecutar, es muy difícil seguir el flujo solo "mirando" el código.

Comment: El código estaba pero por culpa de un mal uso del formato no se veía. He editado para arreglarlo

Comment: Recuerda que con **async** - **await** sería más legible que **then** - **catch**. Por ejemplo, `res = wait features; if (res.ok) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El identificador feats está declarado como variable local en getFeatures
Al ejecutar waitForFeatures su valor siempre es `undefined` porque *no está definido*. Puedes probar algo como

```
const waitForFeatures = async () => {
  if(!document.querySelector('.dynamic-feats')) {
    await getFeatures(); 
  }
```

Pero ten en cuenta de que puedes entrar en una condición de carrera: se ejecuta getFeatures, pero antes de que se complete (y por tanto antes de que inserten en el HTML los features) se puede pulsar un botón y volver a llamar.